# before insert fail in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This Meteor server code tries to fire the collection before insert but no `createdAt` property is being inserted even though the hook is firing.
What am I doing wrong and how to fix it? Thanks

```
// lib/file.js
DataCol = new Mongo.Collection('dataCol');

// serverFile1.js

DataCol.before.insert(function (doc) {
  doc.createdAt = Date.now();
});


// serverFile2.js
myMod = (function(){

  // code...

  return {
   pubMeth: () => {
      DataCol.insert(someDoc);
    }
  }

}());

// serverFile3.js
myMod.pubMeth();
```

Comment: does it work when you specify `function (userId, doc)` instead of just `function (doc)`?

Comment: @tomsp yes it does, why is that?

Comment: @FredJ. the before insert collection hook is expecting to be passed a function that takes two parameters, one for userId and one for doc.  If you pass it a function with just one parameter you will get the userId even if you name the parameter doc (the naming is arbitrary). So in your code you are adding .createdAt to your userId even though it's named doc.

Comment: @Fred J., @mkimmet gave you the answer already. I would have suggested to `console.log(doc)` after adding the `createdAt` field to doc in the hook, just to see what kind of transformation was made on it. Then you would have seen that it is the `userId`. I still find it weird that js allows this kind of operation on a `String`, which just silently fails.